# How To Install Batteries For A System Consists Of Different Components That Work On Different Voltages?

Tags: arduino, batteries, dc-motor, battery-operated, servo

My System Consists Of Three Different Components (Arduino - MicroServos - LED(12v)), ***Can I Install Batteries As Shown  In This Image***?

[image]

***Description:***

Connecting Three Batteries In Series, And Take A Wire After Each Cell To Feed The Component That Uses This Voltage Level,

- **Servos** Will Take A Wire After The ***First Cell***, As They Work On (3-6)v.
- **Arduino** Will Be Connected To The ***Second Battery***, As It Works On (5-12)v.
- **LED** Will Be Connected To The ***Third Battery***, As It Works On (9-12)v.
- All **Grounds** Are Connected To Each Other.

**Will The System Work If It Is Connected As Described**? And Is It Right To Make Such A Connection, Or Should I Make A Separated Source For Each Component?

Comment: This is a Bad Idea. Use the battery pack as one thing, and then use DCDC converters to get the required voltages. Otherwise you are drawing different amount of current from each battery causing damage, extra wear and also making charging a lot more complicated.

Comment: Actually I'm Designing A PCB For This, So Using A DC-DC Converters Is Not An Available Option! Also Voltage Regulators Will Make The Circuit More Complex ...
So, The Best Way To Do This Is Connecting A Separate Batteries For Each Component?!

Comment: No. If you are designing a PCB for this DC-DC converters will be a lot easier than if you weren't using a PCB. How would a PCB make using DC-DC harder to do? Voltage regulators will make the circuit more complicated, in the same way an LED light is more complicated than an filiment bulb. Yes it's more complicated but it's orders of magnitude better.

Comment: mmm, Ok, I May Try To Install A DC-DC Converter On The PCB Using Pin Headers Or Connectors ..

Comment: Or buy one of many DC-DC ICs and solder those in as they're supposed to be used. Going for syncronous SMPS will give you a very efficent system. LT devices (now owend by Analog Devices) have some very good datasheets, making the schematics and layout pretty simple.

Comment: fine, i will look for a dc-dc IC ..

Answer (score 3):

This is a Bad Idea.

I am strongly advising you do not do this.

But it will work.

In your set up, your third cell powers the LEDs. But the second cell powers the LEDs and the Arduino, and the third powers all of the LEDs, Arduino AND the servos.

This will cause you cells to discharge at different rates. Your first cells will drain very quickly, powering everything, which means that you pack will be flat way before your second and third cells are discharged. So this means you need to charge the pack more often. This will increase wear on the cells.

Then to charge them, you’d have to charge each cell up individually. So the first cell would be charged from 10%-100%, while the second is from 50% to 100% and the third basically doesn’t need charging form 90%-100%. So this is complicated.

During use, your pack will have cells at different charge states. This is a Bad Thing for complicated internal battery reasons. So that will damage your cells.

You are using you cells to directly provide the voltage, this means voltage will vary as the cells discharge. You look to be ok with your current set up as each of your sections have their own DC-DC converters, but it is bad practice.

Alternatively you should use the pack as one power source, take power off that and put into DCDC converters so that you have the correct voltage for each module. This will give you better battery life, less battery wear and generally a better system.

Answer (score 1):

As Puffafish mentioned in their answer, this will technically work, but it's likely a very bad idea.

If you decide to do it this way anyway, you will have to add some additional circuitry to make it safe. In particular, you will have to monitor the voltage of each of the cells individually (using your Arduino's analog inputs and some voltage dividers), and you will have to add circuitry to disconnect all of the batteries as soon as any one of them is depleted.

You can use P-Channel MOSFETs (with a BJT to drive them) for this purpose.

Example circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmShf8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Arduino can then disconnect the entire battery pack by pulling the GPIO that's connected to Q1 low. The batteries will stay connected as long as the Arduino keeps that GPIO high.

Make sure to connect the voltage measuring circuitry *after* the MOSFETs (at the MOSFET drain), not directly to the batteries. If you connect them directly, the voltage dividers will over-discharge the batteries even when they're already depleted and disconnected.

Additionally, not every MOSFET will work for this purpose. I've carefully chosen the ZXMP3A16 because that particular MOSFET will work due to its low threshold voltage.

Charging of the batteries will also be a problem. You will either have to charge all cells individually, or go through an extended balancing cycle every time you want to charge the battery pack. Puffafish's answer has more details on this.